# What happened to the children Wallace was looking after?

Tags: the-wire

In *The Wire* Wallace takes care of quite a few children. When he returns to the house at the end of series 1, they're all gone. Where?

Poot and Bodie didn't kill them (they weren't wild about killing Wallace) so where did they go?

Answer (score 3):

The question regarding the fate of the children is not answered anywhere in the series (or in it's companion piece, 'The Wire - Truth Be Told' written by Rafael Alvarez), but looking at other plot lines, specifically Randy's story from season 4, it is likely that they were taken into statutory social care.

Comment: That seems reasonable, just odd they did that and never tried to explain it.

Comment: I know, I just do not think it was ever a relevant part of an already crowded story line. Its my belief that they made a point of showing Wallace's domestic situation to highlight the pressure he was under to continue avoiding school and engaging in the drug trade and to re - enforce the lack of proper parental supervision in the poorer areas of West B'More.